# Обмен данными между двумя программами в Linux

Tags: c++, linux, c

Здравствуйте!

В некоем устройстве имеется встраиваемый компьютер (MOXA IA240LX на Linux), который собирает данные с модулей, датчиков и т.п. Компьютер выступает мастером (на одном порту RS) на шине RS485 и одновременно слейвом (второй порт RS). Соответственно необходимо полученные мастером данные передавать в программу слейва для запроса.

Так как в программировании я не силен, то я реализовал этот обмен с помощью чтения/записи в файл .txt, но очень редко проскакивают данные, не соответствующие действительности.

Я начал искать правильные способы решения и наткнулся на статью "Межпроцессное взаимодействие linux" (https://habrahabr.ru/post/122108/), в которой указывается реализация такого обмена с помощью mutex.

Является ли это правильным решением? Или есть проще и эффективнее? Как я сказал, в программировании не силен. Спасибо!

Comment: Если вы творчески переработаете наименованные каналы для вашего случая, то вполне. Не совсем понятно значение наличия двух каналов, RS485 вполне себе дуплексный. Записывайте и читайте два разных файла. Каждая сторона записывает только в свой файл, и только читает чужой - в этом случае какие то супер ухищрения особенно не нужны. За исключением необходимости следить за размерами файлов. К примеру раз в минуту создавать новый и раз в пол часа удалять все старые файлы.

Comment: но а лучше всетаки нормально используйте RS485 ардуинщики пожалуй нормальное направление поиска https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/SoftwareSerialRS485Example

Comment: Два канала - на первом устройство выступает мастером, на втором слейвом (нельзя на одном порту быть и тем и тем). Но вопрос все равно не в этом. Я хотел именно узнать как убрать вероятность ошибки при чтении из файла.

Comment: В два разных файла пишите, каждая сторона следит за собой в плане записи и коллизи не возникает, это основной возможный источник ошибки. Простенкую чексумму тоже введите, на всякий - для валидации данных, чтобы быть уверенным что канал не причем, тот же CRC32. https://sourceforge.net/projects/crccalculator/files/CRC/ И мастер слейв это же вроде просто модбусовская абстракция, а не физические возможности RS485. Но действительно я уже практически все забыл.

Answer (score 1):

Я не понимаю ситуацию... На ОДНОМ компьютере есть ДВА процесса, которые должны обмениваться информацией? А каким боком тут последовательный порт?! Или, всё-таки есть ДВА компа, которые связаны по последовательной шине?

Если Ваши процессы выполняются (физически) на одном компе, то использование СОМ-порта лишено всякого смысла. Зачем ?!!! Вы совершенно правильно начали копать в сторону "Межпроцессное взаимодействие linux", но использование mutex-ов Вам абсолютно не нужно - слишком низкий и примитивный вид взаимодействия процессов.

Я думаю, что Вам, как не шибко опытному программисту, понятнее всего (а значит - проще) использовать т.н. "именованные каналы".

1) Создаёте именованый канал

```
mkfifo pipe1
```

2) В мастере открываете этот канал на запись

```
open("pipe1", O_WRONLY)
```

3) В подчинённом - открываете на чтение:
    open("pipe1", O_RDONLY)

4) После этого в мастере используете обычный write(...);?, в подчинённом - read(...);

5) Все заботы о проверке ошибок, синхронизации и т.д. берёт на себя ОС.

В качестве РАБОТАЮЩЕГО примера привожу листинги двух крохотных программулек, одна из которых пишет строку в канал, а другая её читает.

Итак, первое действие - создаём канал:

```
mkfifo exampl
```

Второй шаг - пишем и компилируем программу чтения из канала:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

FILE *ff;
char line[256];

    ff = fopen("exampl", "ro");
    if (ff) {
        fgets(line, 255, ff);
        line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
        printf("Прочитали из канала: '%s'\n", line);
        fclose(ff);
    } else
        perror("Ошибка открытия FIFO:");
}
```

Третий шаг - пишем и компилируем программу записи в канал:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

FILE *ff;

    ff = fopen("exampl", "wo");
    if (ff) {
        fprintf(ff, "Пишем в канал\n");
        fclose(ff);
    } else
        perror("Ошибка открытия FIFO:");
}
```

Последний шаг - тестируем полученные программы :

```
$ ./main_r &
[1] 6096
$ ./main_w
Прочитали из канала: 'Пишем в канал'
[1]+  Готово            ./main_r
```

Так как использовал только один терминал, то программу чтения запустил в фоне (&). Она повисла на ожидании ввода. Запустил программу записи в канал. Она записала строчку и завершилась. Программа чтения приняла строчку из канала и завершилась.

Что может быть проще ?!

Comment: С именованными каналами не все так просто - при использовании write/read следует учитывать, что данные представлены потоком и дробить на сообщения нужно самостоятельно. В этом плане удобнее unix domain сокеты (не путать с обычными сокетами).

Comment: **дробить на сообщения нужно самостоятельно** - можно же дробить их на сообщения так же, как во всех остальных символных потоках - с помощью символа конца строки '\n'.

Если нужно использовать записи фиксированной длины (двоичные), то можно воспользоваться механизмом сообщений - man 3 msgget (в варианте SystenV), man 3 mq_receive (в варианте POSIX).

Это будет гораздо проще и понятней, чем организовать обмен через сокеты. Всё-таки, соекты - это БАЗОВЫЙ уровень. О каналы и очереди - это уже сервисы...

Comment: Конечно можно все это сделать руками, но зачем когда можно одной командой записать в unix domain socket сообщение, и другой прочитать.

Comment: **можно одной командой записать в unix domain socket сообщение** - что-то я плохо представляю, что это за КОМАНДА, которая пишет в сокет... В программе (IMHO) используются операторы, вроде... И для работы с сокетами их должно быть гораздо поболее одного.

Предлагаю  TS самому решить, что проще. Вот мой вариант:

Comment: В командной строке выполняю ОДНУ команду:

    mkfifo exampl

Это я создал именованный канал.

Comment: Не смог вставить сюда листинг крохотной программки, попробую сейчас подправить свой исходный ответ.

Comment: я не собираюсь с вами спорить в теме, в которой вы плаваете, если вы считаете, что для случая тк удобнее потоки, это ваше право, я считаю что данный случай лучше ложится на сообщения в UDS, простыми командами recv и write, операторами, если вам угодно. Пишу это так как имею опыт подобных задач и варианте потока и в варианте сообщений.